# CherryPy index path

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have an app where the `/index` path has a special meaning. I don't want path `/` to be synonymous with `/index`. Right now, when I access `/`, cherrypy internally redirects me to the `index` view (object method).

How do I route the path `/` to some view other than `index`? For example, in my case, I want it to be synonymous to `/status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to [mount](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/tree.html#cherrypy.tree.mount) `/` to the same location as `/status`, somewhere in your code you probably have may have a line something like this:

```
cherrypy.tree.mount(Status(), '/status', config)
```

Change it to the following:

```
status = Status()
cherrypy.tree.mount(status, '/status', config)
cherrypy.tree.mount(status, '/', config)
```

Comment: I'm using `cherrypy.quickstart(Server(), config)`. I'll look into this `tree.mount` and see how it fits in. Cheers.